# Is any way to get access to derived class type for abstract one

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I want to make a data class that will contain some information and provide an `event` to work with that information.

```
public abstract class EventData<T> where T : EventData<T>
{
    Action<T> action_;
    public void Subscribe(Action<T> _actor) { action_ += _actor; }
    public void Unsubscribe(Action<T> _actor) { action_ -= _actor; }
    public void Dispatch(T _data) { if (action_ != null) action_(_data); }
}

public class ConcreteEventData : EventData<ConcreteEventData>
{
    int arg1;
    string arg2;
}
```

So, I forced to use that uncomfortable construction `ConcreteEventData : EventData<ConcreteEventData>` instead of simple and short `ConcreteEventData : EventData` even if I keep in mind that I would use the same type as I've described.
Moreover, if someone will use that base class, he may write something like:

```
public class AnotherConcreteEventData : EventData<ConcreteEventData>
{
    float arg1;
    bool arg2;
}
```

As you can see, it is not a good way to use that idea, is there another one to use it more elegance?

Comment: I fail to see why "So, I forced to use that uncomfortable construction"? what do you want to achieve, from the perspective of someone using that type?

Comment: "The user of the class might make a mistake" is generally not an option you can ever completely exclude. When the mistake is obvious, hurts only the consumer and is easily discovered it tends not to matter. That said, your general design smells of an unnecessary reinventing of `EventHandler`/`EventArgs` or `IObservable`. One of the best ways to prevent people from making mistakes is to allow them to reuse what they already know.

Comment: @dlatikay i want to make an event bus with simple static methods like `Subscribe<T>(Action<T> _action, string _id) where T : EventData` and contains a data about all that events. So i can rephrase it like "i want to make a base class and if you have derived from it, you will able to use it as type iof this EventBus

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually, it is, but i want to make it some... easier to implement for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution was quite simple. Instead of making a class for my "event", i could simple use `EventArgs` as data class with no event needed. 
My goal was use it for EventBus, so instead of doing stuff like

```
public abstract class EventData<T> where T : EventData<T>
    {
        Action<T> action_;
        public void Subscribe(Action<T> _actor) { action_ += _actor; }
        public void Unsubscribe(Action<T> _actor) { action_ -= _actor; }
        public void Dispatch(T _data) { if (action_ != null) action_(_data); }
    }
```

```
    public class EventBus
    {
        static Dictionary<string, EventData> _dict;
    }
```

(moreovere, i cannot do that and i could be forced to find a solution for that problem too)
I can simply use

```
public class EventBus<T> where T : EventArgs
    {
        static Dictionary<string, Action<T>> list;

        public static void SubscribeOnEvent(string _sid, Action<T> _method)
        {
            // Do Stuff...
        }
    }
```

And use it in the way like

```
EventBus<MyData>.Subscibe("myID", (data) => { /*Do stuff...*/ });
```

And now i can use all the data, derived from `EventArgs`. Thanks to @JeroenMostert for the idea.